# any good networking book recommended?

Tags: untagged

i have wanted to learn about networking and how they work.  Are there books or websites that are good for them?   Some things I wanted to learn about:

- how to write a program that works like traceroute / tracert
- how subnet masks work
- how http://192.168.1.105 works
- how http://127.0.0.1 works
- how http://localhost works
- how http://room3pc works
- how smb://room3pc works
- how a LAN works with or without DHCP
- how to connect to a mac using a URL

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1: The Protocols (2nd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321336313) (probably the best book on TCP/IP)
  [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1: The Protocols (2nd Edition) http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/516azk5YVQL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA300_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/516azk5YVQL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA300_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

---

- [The TCP/IP Guide.](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_toc.htm) (free online book)

[alt text http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51HSiV3LppL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51HSiV3LppL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

Answer (score 10):

There is one book you need on your desk: Tannenbaum's [*Computer Networks 5th Edition*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132126958):

[cover courtesy google http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61vW8LrWx4L._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA300_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61vW8LrWx4L._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA300_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

It will cover a wide range of networking topics, with insightful diagrams and most importantly, citations for further reading. It does not restrict itself to TCP/IP or "the internet" but covers a wide range of possible networks, local, cellular, ad-hoc wireless, etc.

Comment: I've learned about cryptography and image/video compression from it :-)

Comment: That's a little too harsh for a beginner honestly. But awesome once you get the basics.

Comment: We used this book at university for first networking class.

Answer (score 3):

I've read all of the books listed by **Ayman**, **jldugger**  and **packs**, and I think they are all excellent suggestions.  The *TCP/IP Guide* is more "How does it work", *TCP/IP Illustrated Volume* is more about the nuts and bolts of the protocol and, is somewhat dated (though still a must have classic for your bookshelf) -  particularly with it's discussion of classful addressing, a topic which the TCP/IP Guide handles masterfully. TCP/IP guide is actually a very good practical intro to the protocol; in addition to providing a phenomenal history of CIDR, it also gives you an insane level of detail on PPP and other protocols not often gone into in much detail.

Tanenbaum is more about the holistic "What do networks consist of." and is an excellent addition to fill out your library.  Comer is a classic which has also taught a lot of people in the networking profession practical TCP/IP.

So, those four books make for an *excellent* library on the topic of TCP/IP networking, and I would really like to suggest one more, which provides a *fundamental* discussion on networking protocols, referencing TCP/IP (among others) as a teaching aid to protocols:
[alt text http://vig-fp.prenhall.com/coverimage/0201634481.jpg](http://vig-fp.prenhall.com/coverimage/0201634481.jpg)

Interconnections is my "Desert Island" book - you can read, and re-read some of the pages and chapters and continue to get deeper insight into the whirling maze of protocols that you interact with.  Highly recommended and I think an must-have for every complete bookshelf on computer networking.

Comment: I have skimmed the Interconnections book and thought it looked pretty dang worthwhile.  I haven't yet added it to my shelf,though.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Comer's Internetworking series for years. It was introduced to me as the text used in Ohio University's networking courses.  It has since become my go to reference book in my professional career.  It describes all the general purpose protocols in depth, as well as excellent diagrams on the different protocol headers. [Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130183806), [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=BuYDAAAACAAJ)

Answer (score 1):

**[IBM Redbooks - TCP/IP Tutorial and Technical Overview](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/gg243376.pdf)** is good both for learning some concepts and as a reference. I didn't have *TCP/IP Illustrated* when I started learning about networks, but fortunately this book helped me a lot.

(I'm not sure if the link points to the latest version)

Answer (score 0):

The Computer Networks, By Andrew Tannenbaum.. The Best Book